# Get values from a JSON string which has special tag in variable names C#

Tags: c#, json, get, json.net, json-deserialization

I get following JSON where i need to extract few data from it.

```
{  
 "id":"400xxtc200",
 "state":"failed",
 "name":"barbaPapa",
 "content-exception":"AccessDenied",
 "input-parameters":[  
    {  
       "value":{  
          "string":{  
             "value":"In"
          }
       },
       "type":"string",
       "name":"Operation",
       "scope":"local"
    },
    {  
       "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"bila"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"VMName",
     "scope":"local"
  },
  {  
     "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"txtc"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"PSUser",
     "scope":"local"
  },
  {  
     "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"dv1"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"Datacenter",
     "scope":"local"
  },
  {  
     "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"tpc"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"ServiceArea",
     "scope":"local"
  },
  {  
     "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"103"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"SQN",
     "scope":"local"
  }
 ],
 "output-parameters":[  
  {  
     "type":"Array/string",
     "name":"tag",
     "scope":"local"
  },
  {  
     "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"AccessDenied"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"Error",
     "scope":"local"
  }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to deserialize the JSON object in to a dynamic object which was successful.I'm using following C# code for the work

```
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
dynamic in_values =    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
string state = in_values.state;
```

If you can see I have some tag names with hyphen in the JSON string.

For example `output-parameters`

I cant use the dot operate because then it will be as like follow

```
in_values.output-parameters;
```

How to extract those values from the JSON string.

Comment: Map it to class and use JsonProperty attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonProperty` in this case.

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "content-exception")]
    public string content_exception { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "input-parameters")]
    public List<InputParameter> input_parameters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "output-parameters")]
    public List<OutputParameter> output_parameters { get; set; }
}

string json = File.ReadAllText("abc.txt");
SampleClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(json);
List<OutputParameter>  ls = obj.output_parameters;
```